# redux-form and react-select with options appearing as user types

Tags: redux-form, react-select

I have a redux-form with a react-select. The expected behaviour is that, as I type in the select field, I call the redux action (by using OnInputChange). But I don't know how to call the action. The line that calls the action is commented in the snippet below, because it fails (`this.props.getArtistSearch(value)`). Any ideas of how to properly call the action as user types in?

```
    class FormApplication extends React.Component {
      submit(values) {
        this.props.submitForm(values)
      }
      getArtist(value){
        //this.props.getArtistSearch(value) --> props is undefined
        console.log(value)
      }
      render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props

    return (
      <form className='content text padding-top-0' onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.submit.bind(this))}>
        <div className='row adjust-form-row'>

          <div className='col-md-6 last-lineup'>
            <div className='row adjust-form-row'>
              <div className='col-md-6'>
                <div className='form-group'>
                  <Field
                    name='dl_artistname'
                    options={this.props.gap.artistSearch}
                    component={props => (
                      <Select
                        {...props}
                        name={props.name}
                        onInputChange={this.getArtist}
                        onChange={(value) => {
                          this.props.requestArtistInstance({id: value.dl_artistid })
                          return props.input.onChange(value != null ? value.dl_artistid : null)}
                        }
                        onBlur={() => props.input.onBlur(props.input.value)}
                        options={props.options}
                        //loadOptions={getOptions}
                        clearable={false}
                        cache={false}
                        backspaceRemoves={false}
                        valueKey='dl_artistid'
                        labelKey='dl_name'
                        value={props.input.value || ''}
                        isLoading={false}
                        disabled={false}
                      />
                    )}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </form>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getArtistSearch: (text) => {
    dispatch(getArtistSearch(text))
  },
  submitForm: (values) => {
    dispatch(submitForm(values))
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Going through your code, I noticed that the custom method you defined, `getArtist` was not bound to your React context so `props` will be undefined. Two possible approaches for this are:

1) bind it in the `constructor` method

```
constructor(){
 super();
 this.getArtist = this.getArtist.bind(this);
}
```

2) Alternatively, bind it in the Select component(Not ideal tho')

```
onInputChange={this.getArtist.bind(this)}
```

Comment: Hi!, With this solution, when I type in something, no text appears in the select, it's like the field looses the focus.